# How do I calculate $\int_1^3$ $x \ln (x)\ dx$ with a given accuracy, using Simpson's rule?

Tags: integration, simpsons-rule

How do I calculate $\int_1^3 x \ln (x)\ dx$ with a given accuracy, in this case $10^{-4}$ using Simpson's rule? The problem I encounter is that the fourth derivative is $=2/x^3$. So how do I go forward to solve $(32/180\cdot n^4)\cdot (2/x^3)$ $\le 10^{-4}$ ? Or am I completely on the wrong track here?

Comment: Do you **have** to use Simpson's Rule?

Comment: I am afraid it has to, the next part of the assignment is to find the exact error(calculating the integral normally)

Comment: For the error, don't you have $$\dfrac{M(b-a)^5}{180 n^4}$$ where $$|f^{(4)}(x)| \le M$$ over the defined range $a \le x \le b$. What is the max of the function you found over that range that you can choose for $M$? Now, you can solve for $n$.

Comment: The maximum of ${2\over x^3}$ on the interval $[1,3]$ is $2.$

Comment: Thank you very much! I totally forgot about what the interval was :/. And just to verify, the answer will be, after rounding up, n=8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the fourth derivative of $x\log x$ on $[1,3]$ is bounded by $2$ in absolute value, hence in order to approximate $\int_{1}^{3}x\log(x)\,dx = -2+\frac{9}{2}\log 3$ within $10^{-4}$ it is enough to apply Simpson rule with respect to a uniform partition of $[1,3]$ in $n$ components, such that
$$ \frac{M(b-a)^5}{180 n^4}=\frac{16}{45 n^4}\leq 10^{-4}. $$
The least $n$ ensuring such inequality is $n=8$, leading to
$$ -2+\frac{9}{2}\log(3)\approx \frac{1}{12}\left[f(1)+4 f\left(\tfrac{5}{4}\right)+2 f\left(\tfrac{3}{2}\right)+4 f\left(\tfrac{7}{4}\right)+2 f\left(2\right)+4 f\left(\tfrac{9}{4}\right)+2 f\left(\tfrac{5}{2}\right)+4f\left(\tfrac{11}{4}\right)+f(3)\right]=\color{green}{2.9437}7\ldots$$
with an actual error of $\approx 1.85\cdot 10^{-5}$.

---

Now, to use values of $\log$ over $[1,12]$ for approximating $\log(3)$ is a bit awkward.
 If you want to avoid such circularity, you may notice that
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{P_5(2x-1)}{1+2x}\,dx = \frac{3061}{30}-\frac{743}{8}\log(3)$$
provides a rational approximation of $\log(3)$, namely $\frac{12244}{11145}=[\color{green}{1; 10, 7}, \color{red}{11, 14}]$, within an error of $10^{-5}$. 
It follows that
$$ \frac{10936}{3715}=[2; 1, 16, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5]=\color{green}{2.9437}41588\ldots $$
is a rational approximation of the given integral within $10^{-4}$.